# Responding replica to a read/write request in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm interested in finding out which Cassandra replica responded to a read or write request performed at the ONE consistency level. Is there some way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Running your queries with [TRACING ON](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html) will get you that information. If you are using the Java driver, most of the trace information can be fetched via the [ExecutionInfo](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html) class which you can get by calling [ResultSet.getExecutionInfo](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#getExecutionInfo--). Else query the system_traces keyspace as the documentation suggests.